# iOS6 Youtube iFrame breaks when hidden and displayed again

Tags: ios, youtube

This works fine in any Browser, but not on iOS6 (did not try it with iOS5)

I got an iFrame with a YouTube Video in it, situated in an overlay. After playing the video and toggle the overlay, the video again is broken. The video will playback in the background (you will hear the sound), but its not visible anymore.

Here's a minimal example:
http://jsfiddle.net/s9M6J/2/

```
<script>
/* jQuery */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('.videowrapper').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});​
</script>

<style>
.hidden{
    display: none;
}​
</style>

<body>
    <a href="#" style="display: block;">toggleVideo</a>
    <div style="background: green; width: 500px; height: 500px;">
        <div class="videowrapper">
            <div id="video1">
                <iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/HMrlFLZFdnQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Does anyone know a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

Got a similar issue when embedding a Brightcove video on a jQuery Mobile page which is shown/hidden via javascript. Works on all desktop browsers and android but not Safari on iOS 6.

According to http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/General-Development/Video-in-show-hide-div-does-not-play-on-iOS/m-p/17558#M2352 a workaround is to hide your videowraper by moving it out of the screen using some CSS like `position:absolute;top:-9999px` then back to normal positioning when you want to show it.

For jQuery Mobile users it means embedding video iframes on multiple `<div data-role="page">` on a single page structure won't work, need to put them on separate html pages.